# Error 2060 occured in Chrome and FireFox but not IE when calling ExternalInterface.addCallBack()

Tags: actionscript-3, externalinterface, addcallback

I search almost the internet but not find the solution.

I just use ExternalInterface.addCallBack() in AS3, and it throws exception when I loaded this swf by Chrome or FireFox. But it's ok with IE.

[The code I used( the last example in this AS3 reference page )](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

I modified the allowScriptAccess to "always" and added Security.allowDomain( "*" )

Browsers' version:

IE: 8.0.6001.18702CO

Chrome: 27.0.1453.94 m

FireFox: 7.0.1

How to fix this iusse?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: how to you embed _swf_ into the html page (html source will be good)?

Comment: what kind of exception it throws?

Comment: Check to make sure your object and embed tags both have an id assigned.

Comment: It throws security exception, and error 2060

Comment: This issue is solved by updating Flash Player version.

Answer (score 2):

A guess: Are you hitting a `file:` URL from your browser?  Instead, use an `http:` URL (which of course means either running an HTTP server locally, or copying the files to a remote HTTP server).